# Framer Motion different Animations for different properties

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion, chakra-ui

I am trying to animate an animation in framer motion using Chakra-ui and Gatsby whereby there is rotation and movement and opacity change.

At the moment the animation works as I intend on the movement on the x axis and rotation using `type:spring` however the 'bounce effect' also affects the opacity.

I have tried to explicitly define the `type:tween` for the opacity property, but this has no effect with the opacity of the object still 'bouncing' too. Here is my code:

```
const Rocketship = ({ top, right, bottom, left, opacity }) => {
        const RocketAnim = motion(Box)
        const transition = {
                default: {
                        type: 'spring',
                        damping: 5,
                },
                opacity: { type: 'tween' },
        }

        return (
                <RocketAnim
                        layoutId="rocketship"
                        initial={{ rotate: 25, x: -100, opacity: 0 }}
                        animate={{ rotate: 45, x: 0, opacity }}
                        whileHover={{ width: '170px', cursor: 'pointer' }}
                        transition={transition}
                        pos="fixed"
                        width={150}
                        top={top}
                        right={right}
                        bottom={bottom}
                        left={left}
...
```

I would be grateful for any advice

Comment: Can you please share full code I can test?

Answer (score 0):

Don't have a complete answer because there isn't enough context, but

1. Your `RocketAnim` should be defined outside of the component since you don't need it recreated ever render
2. You don't have to make it a tween, I would keep it as a spring (the default value) and just set bounce to 0

```
opacity: { bounce: 0}
```

3. If you keep it as a tween, I would try adding a duration to trouble shoot the bouncing.